# Listmodel issue in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I need to get the count of items in the array of my list Model, where array is the one of the element of the list. Kindly refer following code snippet for the same.

I need to get the count of 'lValues' in the list element. (for example in terms of C++ : sizeof. lValues[])

```
ListModel {
        id: primaryList
        ListElement {
            Color: "label"
            lValues: [
                ListElement { lValues: 20 },
                ListElement { lValues: 0  },
                ListElement { lValues: 50 },
                ListElement { lValues: 60 },
                ListElement { lValues: 35 },
                ListElement { lValues: 70 },
                ListElement { lValues: 80 }
            ]
    }
}
```

Thanks in adavnce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what You want?

```
ListModel {
        id: primaryList
        ListElement {
            Color: "label"
            lValues: [
                ListElement { lValues: 20 },
                ListElement { lValues: 0  },
                ListElement { lValues: 50 },
                ListElement { lValues: 60 },
                ListElement { lValues: 35 },
                ListElement { lValues: 70 },
                ListElement { lValues: 80 }
            ]
    }
}
Text {
    text: primaryList.get(0).lValues.count
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but its giving me error "TypeError: Result of expression 'primaryList.get(0).lValues' [undefined] is not an object."
The answer should be 7 because there are total 7 items in lValues array.

Comment: I've just created new QtQuick application with code above (I didn't remove Rectangle and Mousearea from default QT-Creator QML).
And there are "7", no errors.
Can You post Your full version?